Configure python-poppler library on ubi9 container for pdf2image
pip install python-poppler fails as it requires an os package poppler-cpp to be installed and configured correctly.
Moreover installing poppler-cpp is a challenge.
installing the poppler-cpp on various container images like ubi8 and ubi9 with failed attempts. Expecting a solution to install python-poppler using statement in a Dockerfile for python11
